# Reusable increment and decrement functions in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and still practicing all features. I was wondering how can I write reusable functions for increment and decrement based on this code - that's what I have for now but it's repetitive. So I want to use increment/decrement function for two different buttons. [Here's jsfiddle demo!](https://jsfiddle.net/dx407e04/4/)

```
 new Vue ({
  el: "#pomodoro-clock",
  data: {
    breakLength: 5,
    sessionLength: 25,
  },
  methods: {
    addBreak: function(inc){
      this.breakLength += inc;
    },
    subtractBreak: function(dec){
      if(this.breakLength === 1) return;
      this.breakLength -= dec;
    },
    addSession: function(inc){
      this.sessionLength += inc;
    },
    subtractSession: function(dec){
      if(this.sessionLength === 1) return;
      this.sessionLength -= dec;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of reusable methods.

```
methods: {
  inc(property, amt){
    this[property] += amt
  },
  dec(property, amt){
    if (this[property] === 1) return
    this[property] -= amt
  },
  ...
}
```

And in your template:

```
<span class="clock__btn--add" v-on:click="inc('breakLength', 1)">+</span>
<span class="clock__break-length">{{breakLength}}</span>
<span class="clock__btn--subtract" v-on:click="dec('breakLength', 1)">-</span>
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx407e04/6/).

Comment: Thank a lot! I'm gonna use it!

Comment: This code is reusable only in the scope of the component. but can't be access by other components. Shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior If he wants to reuse them in other components then sure, these can be easily moved into a mixin or plugin if needed, but the question didn't ask for that requirement.

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior, thanks for the help! For this purpose, I'm not asking for some advanced solutions, but I will definitely consider it for some more complexed projects.

Comment: @Bert it's always better to use reusable functions as plugin and not in component scope

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file name as `functions.js` and you define all your functions in the file.

```
export default function (Vue) {

    Vue.functions = {

        // increment function
        increment (data, inc) {
            data += inc;
            return data;
        },

        // decrement function
        decrement (data, dec) {
            data -= dec;
            return data;
        }

    }

    Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
        $functions: {
            get: () => {
                return Vue.functions
            }
        }
    })
}
```

you can now import your functions in the `main.js`

```
import Functions from './functions.js'
Vue.use(Functions)
```

## Usage

In components you can your functions object using `this.$functions`

```
new Vue ({
  el: "#pomodoro-clock",
  data: {
    breakLength: 5,
    sessionLength: 25,
  },
  methods: {
    addBreak: function(inc){
      this.breakLength = this.$functions.increment(this.breakLength, inc)
    },
    subtractBreak: function(dec){
      if(this.breakLength === 1) return;
      this.breakLength = this.$functions.decrement(this.breakLength, dec)
    },
    addSession: function(inc){
      this.sessionLength = this.$functions.increment(this.sessionLength, inc)
    },
    subtractSession: function(dec){
      if(this.sessionLength === 1) return;
      this.sessionLength = this.$functions.decrement(this.sessionLength, dec)
    }
  }
});
```

OR to save time you can use directly on the `buttons` using `$functions.functionName`

```
<button @click="breakLength = $functions.increment(breakLength, inc)">Increment Value</button>
```

Hope this helps!